# Bootstrap Menu with several submenus repeats first submenu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

[image]

I Have markup that displays a Bootstrap-4 menu, with say 4 items.

Each menu Item, has a nested-submenu. (and i plan on going deeper)

The First item's submenu displays correctly. (Logistics, Logistics, Logistics)

The Following items does not display its respective submenu, but repeats the first item's submenu. (Logistics, Logistics, Logistics)

Suggestions for any would be appreciated....

I checked my markup, so lines are aligned and all nested correctly.
I found examples of bootstrap menus with only 1 submenu and that worked (obviously).
Having more than 1 submenu creates this problem.

```
<Done>

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Home
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
<a class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-item" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink11" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Applications
</a>


<ul class="dropdown-submenu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink11">

<div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Logistics</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Logistics</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Logistics</a>
            </div>

    </ul>




    <a class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-item" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink12" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Technical Support
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-submenu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink12">

            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/screens/utility.htm">Downloads</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/screens/down_install.htm">Installation</a>

            </div>

    </ul>








    <a class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-item" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink13" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        External Links
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-submenu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink13">

            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-item" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink14" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Logik Center
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-submenu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink14">

                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:window.open('http://logik.pwv.gov.za')">Log Request</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:window.open('http://10.131.15.145/vulindlela/requests_login.htm')">View Request</a>

                        </div>

                </ul>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:window.open('http://xxxxxx')">Persal</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:window.open('http://xxxxxx')">Logis</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:window.open('http://xxxxxxxx/')">BAS</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:window.open('http://xxxxxxx')">Government</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:window.open('http://xxxxxxx')">National </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:window.open('http://www.xxxxxxxx/')">Bank</a>

            </div>

    </ul>



    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/screens/vulhistory.htm">History</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/screens/contactus.htm">Contacts</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/screens/main.htm">Home</a>



</ul>

</li>

</Done>
```

I expect every item's submenu to be displayed, not just a repeat of the first items submenu.

Let me know if I need to provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be down to the way you're nesting the menu. Check below for a working example with 2 drop downs.

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here2</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```